# Desenvolvimento iOS nativo

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Tenho uma dúvida em relação as linguagens disponíveis para o desenvolvimento nativo. Ouvi em um podcast, dizendo que ainda há aplicações que a manutenção é feita em objective-c. Seria bom aprender as duas? Ou focar apenas em Swift?

Comment: Para desenvolvimento e aprendizado creio que Swift seja mais fácil, o que tornaria o processo um pouco menos sofrido, ainda sim não tem como apontar qual escolher, ambas são suportadas. A escolha é mais gosto pessoal, então qualquer resposta aqui provavelmente **será baseada em opiniões**, mesmo que digam que Object-C seja razoavelmente mais rápido e que Swift seja mais rapido para aprender e escrever códigos, ainda sim são variações de escolha pessoal ainda.

Answer (score 3):

Se você seguir na carreira de Developer Mobile-iOS, na grande maioria das vezes pedem Obj-C e Swift, nesse caso é bom aprender os dois. Caso seja pra fazer algo temporário recomendo começar com Swift.

Answer (score 2):

Sou desenvolvedor iOS desde 2012, época que não existia Swift ainda, somente Objective-C. 
Hoje em dia a grande maioria dos projetos é feito em Swift, que a Apple está sempre atualizando, e que a cada dia tem mais recursos, se tornando uma das linguagens mais modernas atualmente.
Então não compensa aprender objective-C? Compensa sim, porém a chance de aparecer um aplicativo que você tenha que dar manutenção é cada dia menor. Então hoje, acho mais válido iniciar com Swift do que com Objective-C.